# Sorting UItableview by distance in Swift

Tags: swift, sorting, distance

I have a `UITableView` being populated from a core data entity to display location names and the lat and long of these location.

I have managed to calculate the distance from the user to the stored location and displayed the distance.

```
        var templat = NSString(string: location.lat)
        var templong = NSString(string: location.long)
        var distinationCoords: CLLocation =  CLLocation(latitude: templat.doubleValue, longitude: templong.doubleValue)
        var distance: CLLocationDistance = distinationCoords.distanceFromLocation(mypoi.sharedlocation)
        classdistance = distance / 1000

        cell.customCellSubTitle?.text = "\(distance)"
```

Now, How can I sort the location by distance from the current location.

I can easily sort by name or any value stored in core data, but the distance need to be calculated from the retrieved data and when I do the calculation it will be to late so sort cells

Please help if you can

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Are you using NSFetchResultController ? If yes store distance to coredata and use NSSortDescriptor to sort them. If you want more help tell me

Comment: You cannot calculate distance in NSSortDescriptor cause you have to use CLLocation & CLLocationDistance.

Comment: What attributes does your core data entity have?

Comment: I am using NSFetchResultController, you cant store distance in core location since it is changing al  the tim. it has to be calculated just when you display uitableview.

Comment: my entity has the following attributes: name, latitude ,longitude, timestamp

Answer (score 0):

For example, your tableview is filled by a list of datas with structure:

```
struct Position {
    var latitude : Double
    var longitude: Double
    //you add a function to compare a position to another
    func getDistance(CLLocation current) -> double {
        //calculate the distance here
    } 
}
```

then, with your list of positions

```
var positions = ... the list of positions ...
positions.sort({$0.getDistance(currentPos) > $1.getDistance(currentPos)})
```

The idea here is to use .sort feature of Array in swift to sort your list. You have to define your .getDistance() in order to sort the array correctly.

If you have an NSManagedObject to fetch a tableviewcell, you can use extension to add getDistance to your NSManagedObject. 
For example, your class named 'Foo' (which contains name, latitude ,longitude, timestamp), you can add an extension like

```
extension Foo {
    func getDistance(CLLocation current) {
        //your calculation using Location API
    } 
}
```

Comment: My tableview is using coreData not a list
let location = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as myLocations

Comment: You can use extension in Swift to add the function getDistance for your NSmanagedObject. See my updated answer